# NetLogo Sandpile Model - Code Required to Enhance Model

Tags: performance, netlogo

The below code relates to the NetLogo Sandpile Model where at each time step a random grain of sand is added. When the count of grains of sand exceeds a threshold limit it will trigger an avalanche type event.

I now want to enhance this model with further code so that at each tick (prior to the random grain of sand being added) the code now executes the following rules:

(1) Each patch count will increase its count (n + 1) if the majority of its 8 neighbours are n > 1.

(2) Each patch count will decrease its count to (n = 0) if the majority of its 8 neighbours are n < 1.

It will then move to the second step with the random addition of a grain of sand as in the original code below:

---

```
xtensions [sound]
globals [
  ;; By always keeping track of how much sand is on the table, we can compute the 
  ;; average number of grains per patch instantly, without having to count.
  total
  ;; We don't want the average monitor to updating wildly, so we only have it 
  ;; update every tick.
  total-on-tick
  ;; Keep track of avalanche sizes so we can histogram them
  sizes
  ;; Size of the most recent run
  last-size
  ;; Keep track of avalanche lifetimes so we can histogram them
  lifetimes
  ;; Lifetime of the most recent run
  last-lifetime
  ;; The patch the mouse hovers over while exploring
  selected-patch
  ;; These colors define how the patches look normally, after being fired, and in 
  ;; explore mode.
  default-color
  fired-color
  selected-color
  threshold-color


]

patches-own [
  ;; how many grains of sand are on this patch
  n
  ;; A list of stored n so that we can easily pop back to a previous state. See
  ;; the NETLOGO FEATURES section of the Info tab for a description of how stacks
  ;; work
  n-stack
  ;; Determines what color to scale when coloring the patch. 
  base-color
]

;; The input task says what each patch should do at setup time
;; to compute its initial value for n.  (See the Tasks section
;; of the Programming Guide for information on tasks.)
to setup [setup-task]
  clear-all

  set default-color blue
  set fired-color red
  set selected-color green

  set selected-patch nobody
  ask patches [
    set n runresult setup-task
    set n-stack []
    set base-color default-color
  ]
  let ignore stabilize false
  ask patches [ recolor ]
  set total sum [ n ] of patches
  ;; set this to the empty list so we can add items to it later
  set sizes []
  set lifetimes []
  reset-ticks
end

;; For example, "setup-uniform 2" gives every patch a task which reports 2.
to setup-uniform [initial]
  setup task [ initial ]
end

;; Every patch uses a task which reports a random value.
to setup-random
  setup task [ random error-count ]
end

;; patch procedure; the colors are like a stoplight
to recolor
   set threshold-color threshold + 2
   set pcolor scale-color base-color n 0 threshold-color
end

to go
   if ticks = time 
    [ sound:play-note "Trumpet" 60 64 2 stop ]
  let drop drop-patch
  if drop != nobody [
    ask drop [
      update-n 1
      recolor
    ]
    let results stabilize animate-avalanches?
    let avalanche-patches first results
    let lifetime last results

    ;; compute the size of the avalanche and throw it on the end of the sizes list
    if any? avalanche-patches [
      set sizes lput (count avalanche-patches) sizes
      set lifetimes lput lifetime lifetimes
    ]
    ;; Display the avalanche and guarantee that the border of the avalanche is updated
    ask avalanche-patches [ recolor ask neighbors4 [ recolor ] ]
    display
    ;; Erase the avalanche
    ask avalanche-patches [ set base-color default-color recolor ]
    ;; Updates the average monitor
    set total-on-tick total
    tick
  ]
end

to explore
  ifelse mouse-inside? [
    let p patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor
    set selected-patch p
    ask patches [ push-n ]
    ask selected-patch [ update-n 1 ]
    let results stabilize false
    ask patches [ pop-n ]
    ask patches [ set base-color default-color recolor ]
    let avalanche-patches first results
    ask avalanche-patches [ set base-color selected-color recolor ]
    display
  ] [
    if selected-patch != nobody [
      set selected-patch nobody
      ask patches [ set base-color default-color recolor ]
    ]
  ] 
end

;; Stabilizes the sandpile. Reports which sites fired and how many iterations it took to
;; stabilize.
to-report stabilize [animate?]
  let active-patches patches with [ n > threshold ]


  ;; The number iterations the avalanche has gone for. Use to calculate lifetimes.
  let iters 0

  ;; we want to count how many patches became overloaded at some point
  ;; during the avalanche, and also flash those patches. so as we go, we'll
  ;; keep adding more patches to to this initially empty set.
  let avalanche-patches no-patches

  while [ any? active-patches ] [
    let overloaded-patches active-patches with [ n > threshold ]
    if any? overloaded-patches [
      set iters iters + 1

    ]
    ask overloaded-patches [
      set base-color fired-color
      ;; subtract 'threshold' amount from this patch
      update-n -4
      if animate? [ recolor ]
      ;; edge patches have less than four neighbors, so some sand may fall off the edge
      let selected-neighbors n-of 4 neighbors 
      ;; World is wrapped horizonatlly and vertically so we can always select 4 random neighbors.
      ;; However, we only want to select neighbors which are on the table.
      ;; That is what the next section of code does.
      set selected-neighbors selected-neighbors with [ 
        (abs (pxcor - [ pxcor ]  of myself) < 2) ;; selects patch < 2 from myself which is one patch away.
        and
        (abs (pycor - [ pycor ]  of myself) < 2)
        ] 
      ask selected-neighbors  [
        update-n 1
        if animate? [ recolor ]
      ]
    ]
    if animate? [ display ]
    ;; add the current round of overloaded patches to our record of the avalanche
    ;; the patch-set primitive combines agentsets, removing duplicates
    set avalanche-patches (patch-set avalanche-patches overloaded-patches)
    ;; find the set of patches which *might* be overloaded, so we will check
    ;; them the next time through the loop
    set active-patches patch-set [ neighbors ] of overloaded-patches
  ]
  report (list avalanche-patches iters)
end

;; patch procedure. input might be positive or negative, to add or subtract sand
to update-n [ how-much ]
  set n n + how-much
  set total total + how-much
end

to-report drop-patch
  if drop-location = "center" [ report patch 0 0 ]
  if drop-location = "random" [ report one-of patches ]
  if drop-location = "mouse-click" and mouse-down? [
    every 0.3 [ report patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor ]
  ]
  report nobody
end

;; Save the patches state
to push-n ;; patch procedure
  set n-stack fput n n-stack
end

;; restore the patches state
to pop-n ;; patch procedure
  ; need to go through update-n to keep total statistic correct
  update-n ((first n-stack) - n)
  set n-stack but-last n-stack
end
```

Comment: where precisely in your attempt to code this yourself did you get stuck?

Comment: The problem i have is a lack of knowledge of NetLogo.  The above is a piece of open source code which i am seeking to enhance by the addition of code which applies the new rules.  I am sure it is fairly straight forward, but my knowledge isn't there yet!

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of : if neighbors (with n > 1) > 4 update-n 1 and if neighbors (with n > 1) < 4 update-n 0?

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track, more or less, but about showing us your best effort to write it using actual NetLogo code? And if there's an error message at the point where you got stuck, be sure and include that. The NetLogo User Manual and Sample Models have tons and tons of examples of how to use primitives such as `if` and `with`. You'll want `count`, too. If you get stuck on some particular point of usage, open a new question that's just about that specific point.

Comment: Hey!  Thanks for the advice.  I will try and work it out with the prompts you have given me.